# python question about class printing output

Tags: python

```
class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        ranks = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
        suits = ['C', 'D', 'H', 'S'] 
        self.cards = []
        for s in suits:
            for r in ranks:
                self.cards.append(Card(r,s))
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str([str(card) for card in self.cards])

    def draw(self):
        return self.cards.pop()   
    
    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.cards)
    
    def deal(self,n):
        deal =[]
        for i in range(n):
            deal.append(self.cards.pop())
            
        return deal
d=Deck()
print(d.deal(5))

output:
[<__main__.Card object at 0x0000013493F816D0>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0000013493F81100>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0000013493F82160>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0000013493F818B0>, <__main__.Card object at 0x0000013493F6FF40>]
```

My code prints data information..

I don't know where I did wrong in the code.

Also, is there a way to get a nicer output for deck?

I want my deck to be printed in the shell like this

nice and organized. Thank you in advance

```
 2 C, 3 C, 4 C, 5 C, 6 C,
 7 C, 8 C, 9 C, T C, J C,
     ....
 J S, Q S, K S, A S
```

Comment: self.cards.append(Card(r,s)), here you append a clas to cards. Not a number or string.

Comment: You don't show your `Card` class, but it is clearly missing a `__str__` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can override the card ****str**** method like this

```
import random


class Card:
    def __init__(self, r, s):
        self.r = r
        self.s = s

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.r, self.s)


class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        ranks = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"]
        suits = ["C", "D", "H", "S"]
        self.cards = []
        for s in suits:
            for r in ranks:
                self.cards.append(Card(r, s))

    def __str__(self):
        return str([str(card) for card in self.cards])

    def draw(self):
        return self.cards.pop()

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.cards)

    def deal(self, n):
        deal = []
        for i in range(n):
            deal.append(str(self.cards.pop()))

        return deal


if __name__ == "__main__":
    d = Deck()
    print(", ".join(d.deal(5)))
```

Comment: Thank you sir, would you mind giving me any idea for a nicely organized square-shaped output as I described?

Comment: you could use a while loop and achieve it.